# Type Error: An unhandled exception occurred: NGCC failed

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, visual-studio-code, npm-install

I try to start up my web app by 'ng serve', I get this error. Can't figure out why.

I tried update many packages but it not help,

I am not really sure what the error is even telling me. I have tried to update all dependencies. I have looked at almost all the similar question solutions and they have not worked. I can't tell if it is a compiler error, typescript, or a dependency error.

> `[error] Error: NGCC failed. at NgccProcessor.process (C:\Users\9090\Documents\project\FR\client\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ngcc_processor.js:69:19) at C:\Users\9090\Documents\project\FR\client\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:576:31 at SyncHook.eval [as call] (eval at create (C:\Users\9090\Documents\project\FR\client\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:7:1) at SyncHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\Users\9090\Documents\project\FR\client\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20) at Object.webpack [as webpackFactory] (C:\Users\9090\Documents\project\FR\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:55:30) at createWebpack (C:\Users\9090\Documents\project\FR\client\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\webpack-dev-server\index.js:21:36) at Object.runWebpackDevServer (C:\Users\9090\Documents\project\FR\client\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\webpack-dev-server\index.js:47:12) at SwitchMapSubscriber.project (C:\Users\9090\Documents\project\FR\client\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\index.js:164:32) at SwitchMapSubscriber._next (C:\Users\9090\Documents\project\FR\client\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\switchMap.js:49:27) at SwitchMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\9090\Documents\project\FR\client\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:66:18) at C:\Users\9090\Documents\project\FR\client\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeToPromise.js:7:24 at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)`

My package.json:

```
 {
  "name": "Client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.1.0",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^10.0.1",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^10.0.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^10.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^10.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^10.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.14",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^4.4.2",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^4.4.2",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^4.4.2",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^4.4.2",
    "acorn": "^6.4.1",
    "agm-direction": "^0.7.9",
    "angular-fusioncharts": "^3.0.4",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "core-js": "^2.6.11",
    "events": "^3.1.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fullcalendar": "^3.10.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "install": "^0.12.2",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "primeicons": "^1.0.0",
    "primeng": "^8.1.1",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.0",
    "save": "^2.4.0",
    "sweetalert": "^2.1.2",
    "sweetalert2": "^9.15.3",
    "tslib": "^1.13.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1000.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^10.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.17",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^6.14.10",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^5.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.4.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~3.4.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: The number of your angular dependencies are of incompatible versions, 8 and 10